# How to convert this code from Swift to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

```
private var distance: Double {
    return fabs(max - min)
}
```

How to define this variable in Objective C language.

Comment: what is fabs , is it a function?

Comment: @triple.s: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fabs.html.

Answer (score 2):

In your .m file:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) double distance;
@end

@implementation MyClass

-(double)distance {
    return fabs(max - min);
}

@end
```

Comment: better to use `CGFloat` in Objc